# How to create a custom c++ class to use with blueprint

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, unreal-engine4, build-error, unreal-blueprint

I am trying to create a custom class that i can then use in my blueprints. I need this class to hold player information like name and a path to their picture. What I have made so far doesn't compile or build without errors and I don't know how to fix it since I have never worked with this

```
header file #pragma once

#include "Object.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "PlayerClass.generated.h"

/**
 * 
 */
UCLASS()
class PROTOTYPE2_API UPlayerClass : public UObject
{
 GENERATED_BODY()
public:
 UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Switch Variables");
 string playerName;
 UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Switch Variables")
 string playerTeam;
 UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Switch Variables")
 string picPath;
 UPlayerClass(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer);
 UFUNCTION()
 void importPic(string picPath);


};
```

.cpp file

```
#include "Prototype2.h"
#include "PlayerClass.h"

UPlayerClass::UPlayerClass(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer)
: Super(ObjectInitializer)
{
   playerName = "";
   playerTeam = "";
   picPath = "";
}

void UPlayerClass::importPic_Implementation(Fstring picPath)
{

}
```

Comment: What do you actually mean _blueprints_?? How do you steer your class generator?

Comment: i'm using unreal engine 4 and they allow you to use code and blueprints interchangeably, so blueprints are like a visual way to code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I found is that my importPic function needs

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "Import")
 virtual void ImportPic(const FString& Path);
```

and depending on if you want your class to show up as a blueprint variable or to be able to be made into a blueprint class you would change the top heading to

```
UCLASS(BlueprintType) // for blueprint to show up as variable
UCLASS(Bleuprintable) // for blueprint to be able to be made as a blueprint class
```

the code that built and compiled:

header file

```
#pragma once

#include "Object.h"

#include "PlayerClass.generated.h"

UCLASS(BlueprintType)
class PROTOTYPE2_API UPlayerClass : public UObject
{
   GENERATED_BODY()
public:
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Player Variables")
FString playerName;
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Player Variables")
FString playerTeam;
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Player Variables")
FString picPath;
UPlayerClass(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer);
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "Import")
virtual void ImportPic(const FString& Path);


};
```

.cpp -

```
#include "Prototype2.h"
#include "PlayerClass.h"

UPlayerClass::UPlayerClass(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer)
: Super(ObjectInitializer)
{
   playerName = "";
   playerTeam = "";
   picPath = "";
}

void UPlayerClass::ImportPic(const FString& Path)
{

}
```

Comment: Do I have to inherit from UObject to make class visible in editor so I could make blueprint of it?